# Use Microsoft CryptoGraphicPublicBlobType.Capi1PublicKey in Java

Tags: java, windows-runtime, encryption-asymmetric

Public key is generated into WinRT application using the code below

```
AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider asymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.get_RsaPkcs1());
CryptographicKey cryptographicKey = asymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.CreateKeyPair(1024u);
IBuffer buffer = cryptographicKey.Export(3);
IBuffer buffer2 = cryptographicKey.ExportPublicKey(3);
byte[] inArray;
CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffer, ref inArray);
byte[] inArray2;
CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffer2, ref inArray2);
CommonMethods.PrivateKey = Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
CommonMethods.PublicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(inArray2);
```

In ExportPublic Key 3 refers to CapiPublicKey. If I want to use the base64 encode public key string into java application how can I do that.

Java do not have any thing like CapiPublic Key.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any direct method to do that. I first converted CapiPublicKey to X509 public key supported by java in WinRT itself.

then I used the generated public key into java.